# Default rsync options per remote host

Tags: rsync, configuration

Is there a way to specify default rsync options per remote host? E.g. I have a NAS at 192.168.100.12; its rsync path is `/opt/bin/rsync` and its SSH port is 2222. It sucks to have to manually specify `--rsync-path=/opt/bin/rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222'` at every invocation of the rsync command.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` does not have a config file.

You can use an alias in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias nassync="rsync --rsync-path=/opt/bin/rsync -e 'ssh -p 2222'"
```

Answer (score 1):

## SSH Config

You can set any ssh options in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host nas
    Hostname my-home-nas.duckdns.org
    Port 2222
    User app
```

Then whenever you reference `nas` by a command that uses SSH, those options will be applied:

```bsh
rsync -avhP --bwlimit=5000 --size-only ./data/ nas:/backup/data/
```

## PATH

On the remote system you can probably set `export PATH=/opt/bin/:${PATH}` near the top of `~/.profile` so that `/opt/bin` is preferred over `/usr/local/bin`.

## As a Command

If you want the command to be accessible by other users, or by commands that don't have a login profile, you could create a bash script for the rest:

`/usr/local/bin/nas-rsync`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u

# --size-only so that metadata differences between FAT and EXT3
# or APFS don't cause retransfer

# add --bwlimit=5000 to limit bandwidth to 5MB/s - usefulif you have
# a really dumb switch that won't let other devices communicate when
# one device is maxing out a 100mbps connection

rsync -avhP --size-only -bwlimit=5000 /home/app/data/ nas:/backup/data/
```